# How to select authors and their most commented article?

Tags: sql, join

I have this 3 tables :

```
author: id_author, name_author

article: id_article, text_article, id_author

comment: id_comment, text_comment, id_article
```

and i wonder if i can select every author and their most commented article ?

I have something like this:

```
SELECT a.name_author, art.text_article
FROM author a
INNER JOIN article art on art.id_author=a.id_author;
```

And i have no idea how should I pick only this articles that are most commented for each author .

Comment: Your model looks inconsistent: `comment_id` should not be in `article` table,  but `article_id` in `comment` table. Since single comment is related to single article, but one article has many comments

Comment: well right, my bad

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use dense_rank() for this task. My codes:

```
WITH comments 
     AS (SELECT name_author, 
                article.text_article      AS text_article, 
                Count(comment.id_comment) AS comment_count 
         FROM   author 
                INNER JOIN article 
                        ON author.id_author = article.id_author 
                INNER JOIN comment 
                        ON article.id_article = comment.id_article 
         GROUP  BY name_author, 
                   article.text_article), 
     best_articles 
     AS (SELECT name_author, 
                text_article, 
                Dense_rank() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY name_author 
                    ORDER BY comment_count DESC) AS rank1 
         FROM   comments) 
SELECT name_author, 
       text_article 
FROM   best_articles 
WHERE  rank1 = 1
```

I created https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7e4711990f6ec9c88657199fc0f1afa for you.

Comment: `DENSE_RANK` can also be used in the same query as `GROUP BY` and so applied to aggregated results.